# Uploading multiple photos like Facebook

Tags: php, jquery, flash

Anyone know what tool does facebook use for uploading multiple photos? It is so neat!

It look like they are using flash uploader? If so, which one out there has similar to that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend to have a look at [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), which is from the developers that brought us TinyMCE. It has the ability to use different "engines" depending on what is installed. The options are

- Google Gears
- Flash
- Silverlight
- BrowserPlus
- HTML 5
- HTML 4

You can specify more than one option and Plupload will automatically choose the next one, if the first option is not installed (and so on).

It is also possible to resize the images automatically before uploading them.

Comment: what type of license is this? is it free for commercial use?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used it they were using a Java Applet uploader, which is pretty popular with on-the-fly uploading, or if you need to plug into the host OS to easily choose files to upload.

Comment: I do remember Java Applet uploader but that was while ago, they dont use it any more.

Comment: java applet uploader is a long time ago.